# Q Value for 64-Zn(n,2n)63-Zn

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I've been looking for the Q-value for this reaction for quite sometime now but haven't had any luck with it.

What is the Q-value for the equation and how much energy would each of the neutrons produced have?

The threshold for this reaction is an incident 12.05 MeV with Zn-64 at ground state.

Comment: What is understood by the $Q$-value?

Comment: (Energy of products - energy of reactants), to put it in chemical terms.

Comment: As you have a well defined nuclear reaction in hand you can fall back on the evaluated nuclear data files (ENDF). Several versions are maintained by various national agencies.

Comment: @dmckee Whenever I try to search for the energy of the reaction comes up with a "No Data" error page.

Comment: The last time I used them (and it has been a number of years) the available web tools were limited in their ways of understanding the files. I sometimes found it worth parsing them myself. But right above threshold there is generally a region where $Q = E_i - E_\text{threshold}$.

Comment: @dmckee Ei in this case refers to the initial energy of the incoming neutron, correct?

Comment: It is right there in the ENDF data...

Comment: @JonCuster Where/how are you finding this? I'm getting no results for any de reaction or it pops up with code pages.

Comment: Go to ENDF (I prefer Brookhaven). Enter ‘64Zn’ for target, ‘n,*’ for reaction, and ‘sig’ for cross section. Hit search. Scan down the results for the (n,2n) reaction you desire. Read off the Q value.

Answer (score 3):

Go to [ENDF](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/exfor/endf00.jsp), hosted at various places on the internet if Brookhaven is not on the same continent as you. This is a great resource. There is also ENSDF at the same place(s) for nuclear energy levels. For light nuclei, go to [TUNL](http://www.tunl.duke.edu/nucldata/), particlarly for isobar diagrams.

Enter search parameters:
[image: search page]

Hit submit, and get these results (there are many more not in screen shot):

[image: results]

Look at line number 4 - the 64Zn(n,2n)63Zn reaction. Read off the Q-value. For fun, plot the cross section data:

[image: plot]