# Crystals thermal neutrons can pass throw without significant change in their energy

Tags: crystals, neutrons, attenuation

I looked online for a really long time already for crystals which thermal neutrons can pass throw without significant change in their energy. Does anyone here know which crystals have the minimum energy attenuation coefficient for thermal neutrons? (Please contain references)

Comment: The data available at https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/exfor/endf00.jsp can be looked through to find the lowest cross sections by element for thermal neutrons. Finding an appropriate crystal is then up to you.

Comment: I don't know how to use the site, can you help me get into crystal-neutron scattering site please?@JonCuster

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/500964/38675 has a very brief overview.

Comment: Thank you so much @JonCuster